# generating potentiometer adjustable, non-inverted voltage square pulses from microcontroller gpio output

Tags: analog-switch, strobelight

I would like to generate a square signal with SW adjustable duty cycle, phase etc using the output pin of a microcontroller (3.3V). Frequency <100Hz.  However, I also want

1. the amplitude of the high state to be in ~ 2-7V range adjustable with a trim potentiometer from a 12V supply rail,
2. When the signal is low it should be close to zero.
3. no spikes or disconnected states between transitions to high/low
4. signal to be zero when the microcontroller output is zero (non-inverted).

The signal will be fed into high impedance op-amp inputs which will driveflash/strobe circuits, so it is like a common analog input signal to multiple strobe circuits.
What is the simplest way to do this? A mosfet, analog switch IC or ?

Thank you!

Comment: How much current do you need? You can probably use the MCU to drive a mosfet driver to switch the output of a variable buck converter.  100Hz is quite slow.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is simply an N-MOSFET. 99.9% of the time you can do the inversion in the MCU itself and remove U1, but on the off-chance that you can't for whatever reason, add an inverter U1. Also, restrict your pot range by adding lower and upper fixed resistors:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0gfmo.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

An even simpler option is to replace both the inverter and the MOSFET with an open-drain (or open-collector) 12V-tolerant non-inverting buffer.

Comment: probably no big deal, but this will default to output-high, when microcontroller is reset or unpowered. If that is not the desired behavior, a pull-up resistor can be added to U2 gate.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an analog mux. You require "no spikes", this is a vague requirement, but a fast analog mux should meet your needs.

Depending on which analog mux you choose, you may need a level shifter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPOcb2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! The Analog MUX would be a SPDT analog switch, correct? I was wondering about the break-before-make feature of these switches: could there be a problem during the transition between high-low, since the output is briefly floating? I suppose one can add a pull-down resistor to the output of the mux?

Comment: Yes, a SPDT, something like a 4053, but this is an old part, there are probably better options. A pull-down wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

here's another, not particularly precise, but just for variety. pot is 7K. [falstad link](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjOB0AMt-CwFMC0B2EBmSBOMAmAgDkxxyLAFZNDMRKj6QAWTAKABcR818QcAbN2bR+Q0SggTokSuUxgi+IrzDMK5cLE5ZozMVkxDBICRGwCq0HtDRq00TNSEoZckouWr1YTWG0A7sKiRKL4IiyM0GxBmEaRhkKhpjHB4ARpxCkATpk4fOFhlOJacDr40IzKVRHVpuCmspSORjjUaJi2bRgyAtCUaM3MaGj5clRC-tFBhbr6s058YKkVVUSMYGhCdcu5m9vr4FtYlHyiU9p7x3UmdefwbJv6cUKLWETzvA0OsI1ExfoAAoAew4SAAdhwAJbAgC2SDB2RWETe+xOZzYACVuJUEmA+glRKIIhkiY1KFiQAJ5od8dxDmFSr8wLIoCU3KlbodqfSqmwAOa89FCoxRFIzFGnEVS6bSvgvYWynh8W5fLJKknKPIYmZfEydfQmWWYD5zFg8g3cNgADxYuIUjGY6iwhBY4D4ADUAPoAeQAqgAVFa452zZ0a4mMBXh1IK-DFRLujax+JZBVgUnI85a5VJ8VpePbWpfaK2i39fjmEPukDegCSADk2MDwJQQGLmJZ5kSYLA0BR4-UChigA)
[image]